# Date picker JS: how to have it work on multiple form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using this plugin with WP:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-datepicker-alternative/

The .js file includes this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#fieldName1').datepicker({
     autoclose: true
  });
});
```

Does anyone know how to doctor this bit of code so the date picker will function in multiple fields in the same form, such as fieldName2 and fieldName3 as well as fieldName1?

I thank you in advance for your efforts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `id` attribute, assign a meaningful `class` e.g. `datepicker` to the elements you want datepicker on. Then update your javascript to use that class selector.

Example:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="text" id="fieldName1" class="datepicker" />
<input type="text" id="fieldName2" class="datepicker" />

// jQuery
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
     autoclose: true
  });
});
```

**Update:**

If you don't want to use class selectors and would want to use multiple `id`s, then you could do something like following:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="text" id="fieldName1" />
<input type="text" id="fieldName2" />

// jQuery
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#fieldName1, #fieldName2").each(function() {
     $(this).datepicker({
       autoclose: true
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: That would work, but I can't assign a class that will target only the date fields. The plugin that produces the form sets all that itself, and the date fields have no unique class. Is there a way to use multiple field names such as $('#fieldName1','#fieldName2').datepicker({ and so forth?

Comment: @ericjt, yes, that's possible too, but the syntax is a little different from what you have in comment.  Please see updated answer.

Comment: Well, it didn't work. I also tried single quotes around the field names, as well as each name having its own set of single and then double quotes. Only the first field name shows the datepicker (works in all variations). A friend of mine said it might need a loop to work, but he isn't available. Shall we give it another go?

Comment: @Ericjt, I just saw that in `id`s I had leading `#`, I have removed them.  Did you try this answer with or without the `#`?  The loop that your friend is talking about is the `each` in this answer.  Can you give this a try?

Comment: I restored your looped version exactly and removed the # from the two field names and doesn't work at all. Sorry.

Comment: @Ericjt, can you create a jsFiddle of it?  www.jsFiddle.net.

Comment: Correction, it was conflicting with a weather widget (which I did not have in when I was trying it before. Just added that an hour ago). Removed that and it works for both now. Idk what was wrong. Works with single quotes and # marks, like this: $('#wpbdp-field-10, #wpbdp-field-22').each(function() {      THANKS!

Comment: @Ericjt, great.  Glad you sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an ID to identify your Input, use a class to identify multiple Inputs

```
<input id="fieldName1" class="datefield" />

$('.datefield').datepicker({
   autoclose: true
});
```

Comment: I can't use a class as they are not unique from field to field in this form. The date picker would show up where I don't want it.