# Jquery datepickers date issue

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I have a rails application where I am using jquery datepicker with 2 input fields like this.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datePicker" placeholder="Check In" id="dpd1" value="<%= (Date.today).strftime('%d-%m-%Y').to_s %>" name="arrival_date_disp">

<input type="text" class="form-control datePicker" placeholder="Check Out" id="dpd2" value="<%= (Date.today + 1).strftime('%d-%m-%Y').to_s %>" name="departure_date_disp">
```

Jquery code is like this -

```
  $("#dpd1").datepicker({
    minDate : new Date,
    yearRange: "-90:+1",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    altField  : '#arrival_date',
    altFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
    dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
    numberOfMonths: 2
  });   

  $("#dpd2").datepicker({
    minDate : $("#dpd1").datepicker( "getDate" ),
    yearRange: "-90:+1",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    altField  : '#departure_date',
    altFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
    dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    setDate: "31-10-2016"
  });
```

The problem is there is only one datepicker instance being initialized for both fields and as such when I click open the datepicker it shows same date for both of them (obvious as same datepicker is being used).

How do I show different date for second field ?

[first one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWJbE.jpg)

[second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdq4r.jpg)

Comment: Seems to work for me (I change the first date picker to 1 month and keep the second with 2) http://output.jsbin.com/rugowo

Comment: take a look to [this atricle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18326867/3884750)

Comment: I am not talking about the input fields Mosh. They change as expected. I am talking about the calendar which shows same dates for both the fields.